# Non-linear equations Numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

I have no clue on this question. Please help me.

Find an approximate to $80^{1/3}$ correct within $10^{-5}$ using the Bisection method and false position method and compare the rates of convergence.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Similar to your previous question, this is all about setting up an initial equation to work with.
Let $x$ be the value of $80^{1/3}$. We can then write $$x = 80^{1/3}.$$ Can you see what you need to do from here?

Comment: omg...........Thank you...

Comment: what does 10^-5 meaning?

Comment: @HyoDong Kim It wants your solution to be correct to $5$ decimal places. To do this, you make your iterations and stop when two successive iterations are the same to $5$ decimal places.